# Windows Form doesn't disable on Enabled = False

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have these two subroutines which handle a button click event for two buttons on a form. Each one causes another smaller form to be displayed over the window which requires user input before the user may continue.

In both cases I have used Enabled = False to disable to main form while the smaller form is active. In the first Sub, AddNewPatientButton_Click, this has the desired effect of disabling the main form. However, for DeletePatientButton_Click, this has no effect.

Below is the code for the event handlers:

```
Private Sub AddNewPatientButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddNewPatientButton.Click
    NewPatientForm.Show()
    Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub DeletePatientButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DeletePatientButton.Click

    AreYouSureForm.Show()
    Enabled = False

    If AreYouSureForm.yesSelected Then

        Dim sqlQuery As String = "DELETE FROM Patients WHERE "

        Dim firstName As String = PatientDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells.Item(0).Value.ToString()
        Dim lastName As String = PatientDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells.Item(1).Value.ToString()
        Dim dOB As String = PatientDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells.Item(2).Value.ToString()

        dOB = dOB.Substring(0, 2) & dOB.Substring(3, 2) & dOB.Substring(6, 4)

        sqlQuery = sqlQuery & "Firstname = '" & firstName & "' AND Surname = '" & lastName & "' AND DateOfBirth = '" & dOB & "'"

        DatabaseModule.AddOrDelete(sqlQuery, True, True)

    End If

    Enabled = True

End Sub
```

And here is the code for the NewPatientForm that the first event brings up:

```
Public Class NewPatientForm

    Private Sub NewPatientForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Populate the year drop-down box with all of the years between now and 1900
        Dim year As Integer = Date.Today.Year()

        Do Until year = 1899
            YearComboBox.Items.Add(year)
            year -= 1
        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Sub CancelAddButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CancelAddButton.Click
        PatientDatabaseForm.Enabled = True
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OkayButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OkayButton.Click
        Dim sqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO Patients (Firstname, Surname, DateOfBirth) VALUES ("

        'Get inputs
        Dim firstName As String = FirstNameTextBox.Text
        Dim surname As String = LastNameTextBox.Text
        Dim dOB As String = DayComboBox.Text & "-" & MonthComboBox.Text & "-" & YearComboBox.Text

        'Build sql insert string from inputted values

        If (firstName <> "") And (surname <> "") And (dOB <> "--") Then 'If no input, then display message

            sqlQuery = sqlQuery & "'" & firstName & "', "

            sqlQuery = sqlQuery & "'" & surname & "', "

            sqlQuery = sqlQuery & "'" & dOB & "')"

            DatabaseModule.AddOrDelete(sqlQuery, True, False)

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("Invalid input")
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

And the code for the AreYouSureForm that the second event brings up:

```
Public Class AreYouSureForm
    Public yesSelected As Boolean

    Public Sub YesButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles YesButton.Click
        yesSelected = True
        Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub NoButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NoButton.Click
        yesSelected = False
        Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm probably just missing something really stupid, but I can't see it :(

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: "Dont glue"  & " bits of 'strings' " & " together to make " & " 'SQL' " & "queries"

Comment: Oh? How come? It's always worked for me doing it this way.

Comment: AreYouSure `ShowDialog`?

Comment: Thanks, that works :) I didn't know that existed as an option, and I'll use it for all my dialog windows from now on.

Comment: try a patient named `D'Angelo O'Brian`

Comment: Hmmm, I see the issue. So what alternate method would you suggest?

Comment: @PatrickThorpe use parameters.

Comment: There ought be no need to dig data out of a DataGridView to save to the database.  Bind it to a DataTable and let a dataadapter update it for you.

Comment: Be aware that when you use `ShowDialog` you will need to manually dispose of the form after you close it (if appropriate).